# How to delete videos from iMovie on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, imovie

I'm having an issue where I cannot delete anything from the iMovie app on my iPhone 7. How do I delete videos from the iMovie app?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS - not all videos are stored in the camera roll. iMovie would also show videos which are not in the Photos app. They cannot be deleted the usual way.

There are probably several ways to get rid of them, but this one here deletes all:

1. Delete the entire iMovie app from you phone.
2. Install the app again from iTunes or from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Videos in iMovie are from your camera roll. Delete them using the Photos app.